# what is the name of this area blue squared between 2 axs in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting 2 axs in a figure, here is the screenshot

[image]

the whole thing in a figure, the red square and white square are 2 axs, my question is, what is the name of this blue squared area between 2 axs?

Comment: The name is `wspace`, w comes from width I suppose and hence the width spacing between two subplots.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=2)` (change 2 with whatever number you like) to adjust space between two subplots, if that's what you're asking. If you're just asking about the numbers, that's simply the second subplot's vertical (y) axis.